# Adding a linear regression predictor decreases R squared

Tags: regression, linear, r-squared

My dataset ($N \approx 10,000$) has a dependent variable (DV), five independent "baseline" variables (P1, P2, P3, P4, P5) and one independent variable of interest (Q).

I have run OLS linear regressions for the following two models:

```
DV ~ 1 + P1 + P2 + P3 + P4 + P5
                                  -> R-squared = 0.125

DV ~ 1 + P1 + P2 + P3 + P4 + P5 + Q
                                  -> R-squared = 0.124
```

I.e., adding the predictor Q has decreased the amount of variance explained in the linear model. As far as I understand, [this shouldn't happen](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167827/why-is-sum-of-squared-residuals-non-increasing-when-adding-explanatory-variable/167832#167832).

To be clear, these are R-squared values and *not* adjusted R-squared values.

I've verified the R-squared values using [Jasp](https://jasp-stats.org) and Python's [statsmodels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels).

Is there any reason I could be seeing this phenomenon?  Perhaps something relating to the OLS method?

Comment: numerical issues? The numbers are quite close to each other...

Comment: @user2137591 This is what I'm thinking, but I have no idea how to verify this.  The absolute difference in R-squared values is 0.000513569, which is small, but not *that* small.

Comment: I hope you know linear algebra: if $\mathbf{X}$ is the design matrix of the above, could you please compute $\det\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}$, where $T$ is the matrix transpose and $\det$ is the matrix determinant?

Comment: Missing values get auto-dropped?

Comment: 0.000513569 is a very small number: it is 0.41 percent change. It is very possibly a numerical issue. What Clarinetist is trying to say is that maybe your design matrix has a poor condition number and when inverting it is numerically instable...

Comment: @generic_user AH yes this is it. Missing values for Q but not for other columns. If you write your comment into a brief answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Could it be that you have missing values in `Q` that are getting auto-dropped?  That'd have implications on the sample, making the two regressions not comparable.