# Estimating prediction error and confidence band

Tags: confidence-interval, prediction, fitting

Like a lot of amateurs, I would like to see how well the evolution of Covid-19 is predictable. So I imported the data (here, for Italy) and fitted a logistic curve. Then I added the 90% and 95% confidence bounds. I got the following plot:

[image]

Great. The next day, I updated my plot with the latest data and realized that the estimation was had been quite optimistic and the asymptote is now much increased (same scale in both pictures):

[image]

**Questions** I understand that *if the logistic model had been good*, the next point should have been in the confidence range with a probability of 90% (or 95%). Can I conclude that the logistic model is not a good model here? Are there some standard procedures to assess the validity of the prediction by taking into account the uncertainty on the model?

Also, the difference between the two asymptotes gives me an indication of the precision of the prediction (it is not off by 1 or by 10^5 but by about 500 deaths). Is there some classic methods to take this into account?

*Edit* 21/03/2020: clarification in response to hakan's answer

The model I fitted is 
$$\dfrac{c}{1 + a e^{-b x}}$$
and with $a=514434$, $b=-0.276$ and $c=5568$. Of course, this model is the same as @hakanc's, with a different parametrization (e.g. his $K$ corresponds to my $c$). The corresponding covariance matrix is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1.1\times 10^{10}& 641 & -2.5\times 10^7 \\ \star & 3.8\times 10^{-5} & -1.6\\ \star & \star & 80\times 10^3 \end{bmatrix}$$

I believe the low sensitivity to $c$ ($=K$) is described by the $(3,3)$ component of the covariance matrix, $\sigma=\sqrt{80\times 10^3}\approx 280$. So though I understand (and agree with) the argument of low sensitivity, I believe it is already included in the "confidence band".

Comment: Good that you also provided the model and estimated parameters. Do you also have a link to the data? I have previously made [a comment on the interpretation of the estimated parameter covariance matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/391314/120118). Is the third element corresponding to $c$?, it is indeed high but it is in comparison to the other elements. Assuming $a$ is the first element, the diagonal element is of the order $10^{10}$, which is even higher, but the answer is further complicated by the cross correlation between the parameters, that is the number $-2.5\times 10^7$.

Comment: @hakanc I get the data from [this French website](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/coronavirus-covid19-evolution-par-pays-et-dans-le-monde-maj-quotidienne/). I extracted the relevant points (number of deaths in Italy by day) here for your convenience: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/X6uDKtVq).

Comment: Yes, the term $(3,3)$ corresponds to $c$ and $(1,1)$ to $a$. I don't think you can compare the $10^{10}$ and the $80\times 10^3$ because the first one has no dimension and the second one is a number of deaths. The  $(2,2)$ is in inverse of time. 
Thank you for the link on the covariance matrix for estimated parameters.

Comment: I think the answer to my question is, from your linked answer: "_given the data and a model, how much information is there in the data to determine the value of a parameter in the given model. So it does not really tell you if the chosen model is good or not._"

Answer (score 3):

When working with mathematical models, it is always good to check the assumptions of the model. The [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) is often used when modelling population growth, and specifically where the rate of reproduction is proportional to both the existing population and the amount of available resources, all else being equal. Letting $P$ represent population size, the differential equation is

$$
{\displaystyle {\frac {dP}{dt}}=rP\cdot \left(1-{\frac {P}{K}}\right),}
$$
where the constant $r$ defines the growth rate and $K$ is the carrying capacity, see the link for more details. The solution, letting $P_0$ be the initial population, is
$$
P(t)={\frac {KP_{0}e^{rt}}{K+P_{0}\left(e^{rt}-1\right)}}
$$
Thus, this model would be appropriate if Italy did nothing to mitigate the spread of the virus, but they are in fact using [quarantine](https://www.thelocal.it/20200319/italy-set-to-extend-quarantine-period-beyond-april-3-and-tighten-rules). The effect of wrong modelling assumptions would be that if you [cross-validated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) the fitted model, you would get poor results.

Additionally, since the shape of the logistic function is

[image: The curve]

and in your data, it does not seem to include the part where the curve flattens out, I would suspect that the parameter describing that phenomenon, $K$, would have a high variance from your estimation procedure. An intuitive explanation for this can be done by plotting the function for different $K$ and constant $r$:

[image: different_K]

In this figure, if there is only data for $t$ between 0 and 1 would not reveal so much information on $K$, other than if $K$ is around 10, compared to $K > 100$. More formally, assuming you are doing maximum likelihood estimation, you can look at the eigenvalues of the Hessian of the corresponding likelihood function, to see if optimization problem is well conditioned.

Comment: _I would suspect that the parameter describing that phenomenon, K, would have a high variance from your estimation procedure._ Is it not what my plot displays (the band widens with time)?

Comment: Yes, you do have a wide band on $K$, but see my edit on the effects of different $K$. Without data when the curve flattens out, it is hard to use this model I would say.

Comment: I added a few elements in my post, in reaction to your nice answer.